# If $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then $a = b$ or $a = -b$. Is the converse true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I was able to prove the original statement, but I'm stuck on the converse.

If $a = b$ or $a = -b$, then $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$. This holds true for $a = b = 1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I mean, it seems to be true.

Comment: What is your definition of divides? This is automatically true from how I understand it.

Comment: It’s trivial that if $a=b$, then $a\mid b$ **and** $b\mid a$. It’s the other direction $-$ the one in your title $-$ that’s problematic: that implication is true in $\Bbb Z^+$ but false in $\Bbb Z$. $1\mid -1$ and $-1\mid 1$, but $-1\ne 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, the converse is true, that is, we can show that $$(a\mid b \;\;\text {and}\;\;b\mid a )\implies a = \pm b$$

If $a\mid b$, then $b = ma$ for some integer $m$. And if $b\mid a$ then $a = nb$ for some integer $n$...so...

$$b = ma = m(nb) = mn( b) \implies mn = 1 \implies m = n = \pm 1 \;\implies a = \pm b$$

So if you've already proven that if $a = \pm b$, then $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, you now have that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then $a = \pm b$.  And so, together: you have that 
$$a = \pm b \quad \iff \quad a\mid b\;\;\text{and}\;\; b\mid a$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about division in $\mathbb{Z}$.  If so, then the original statement is false.  -7 and 7 divide each other ($-7$ times $-1$ is $7$, and $7$ times $-1$ is $-7$), but they certainly are not equal.\

As for the converse you mentioned, if $a = b$, then there exists an element, namely $1$, such that $1a = b$, hence $a$ divides $b$.  Similarly $b$ divides $a$, since $1b = a$.\

Comment: It says if $a = b$ or $a = -b$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add to the original state "or a = -b". It is true with that added to it.